# Stack Overflow portable edition code on Github

Tags: discussion, data-dump, portable-edition

As [promised yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20823/stack-overflow-portable-edition), I've put the code I used to generate the static mirror [on Github](http://github.com/ghewgill/so-static).

I'll carry on working on it there. Github has fine social networking features, at least compared to (M)SO. :)

Comment: Why the dupe vote?

Comment: Saw it as pretty much like the dupe, save for the fact that this is more an announcement update to that earlier one. So it could have been an addendum.

Comment: I'm getting 403 on your links for http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/

Comment: @Oscar: thanks, that's just to keep you on your toes and encourage you to download the code! :) Seriously, fixed now, my mistake.

Comment: An installer with cassini would be very helpful, unless it works with relative paths?

Answer (score 2):

I'd be happy to help write a .NET class library to process whatever the output format is in C#, to help people write .NET apps should they wish to. I probably haven't got enough time to get heavily involved in working out the format itself though. Just make it portable and we shouldn't have a problem :)

(Of course for portable data formats, there's always Protocol Buffers... :)