# Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, printing

I would like to make a suggestion for a Stack Overflow/Exchange complete Q&A printer-outer.

It would print out the full question, its answers, and  its comments, which the normal web-browser print does not do.

Comment: +1 for asking this question. Much needed feature.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Printing in Firefox is still a disaster.  Printing in IE seems to work OK, but I don't want to have to open IE just to print.  And that assumes I'm at work where I have IE available -- at home I run linux so IE is not an option.

Comment: Just linking http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite

Comment: It's kind of weird that it doesn't just work. Is this 1996? :O

Comment: Really great to see the "status-completed" badge on this. Great work Stack team!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try stackprinter http://www.stackprinter.com/.

Comment: Going to modify my original answer - it's a more readily available solution.

Comment: +1 It would be nice if it can print out many questions based on tag - as mention in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117190/printing-out-a-group-of-stack-overflow-questions-based-on-tag

Comment: Anyway to print in color? It's useful for code highlight

Comment: @NickW I have added the PrettyPrint js library for the code highlighting

Comment: @systempuntoout Thanks. it works great.

Comment: StackPrinter’s layout isn’t great, and worse, it automatically tries to initiate printing instead of just displaying it with a print-stylesheet, but it’s better than nothing.

Comment: @Synetech I'm open for suggestion :), for the printing stuff you can pass `printer=false` on the query string and skip it.

Comment: @systempuntoout, the query term is great, thanks (though that it’s necessary at all is absurd). A nicer stylesheet would be good, and might be implementable as a user-stylesheet in the meantime. I’ll keep an eye out for examples of sites that provide a good print stylesheet, but for now, with the don’t-print query, I’m satisfied (mostly) with StackPrinter (I don’t understand why the print-formatted pages don’t have a link to the original, normal question page).

Comment: It doesn't support this site: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there no way to 'print all' questions or answer by a particular user?

Comment: It doesn't really work. Answers are missing from the print!

Comment: @gravity use the print of your navigator

Comment: @XavierCombelle if you have anything new to add, add it as a new answer.

Comment: @Luuklag Xavier is the author of this answer...

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні which still doesn't give them the right to drastically alter it. What did all previous users vote on then?

Comment: @Luuklag sure, changing it entirely is not the right call. But why not just keep the old content _and_ add the new one? Surely "post another answer" isn't the go-to solution when an existing answer can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with the [SO static dump framework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20823/stack-overflow-portable-edition) that I've started to work on. I don't quite have comments rendering yet (I've been busy with other projects), but the rest of the question/answer data is available in a plain format suitable for printing. Adding comments would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Is there a way to follow what you're doing on this? Like a dev report or something?

Comment: The best place is probably over on Github: http://github.com/ghewgill/so-static Follow that project and you'll be notified of commits or other updates. Along with the obvious code collaboration, there's a wiki and issue tracker and such but I haven't played with the extra features yet. Now is a good chance!

Answer (score 1):

This is completed as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329187/235711

Answer (score 0):

Use the print functionality of your favourite web browser? If you are on Windows <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will work in most cases.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't print comments.

Comment: Right, they are loaded separately. Pity. Smells like a feature request: printer-friendly view.

Comment: Hmm. Where can I make that request?

Comment: Looks like you found out :)

Comment: Thread printer-outer ftw. Thanks guys.

Comment: @StevenWright: As of trying *right now*, this seems to work fine, at least in Chrome. Comments and everything!

Comment: Still fails in Firefox 8.0 on Windows.  E.g. text runs off the bottom of the page and is missing from the next page.

Comment: The browser’s print function would print it as you see it; the question is asking for a print formatted stylesheet.