# "download question" feature

Tags: feature-request

Can we have a "download question" feature on SO, which would let you save the whole question thread (as one long page) or maybe just as xml or text or anything.

Update: [StackPrinter](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/) can do that

Comment: Tried printing then? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/printing-out-stackoverflow-questions

Comment: Duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/21541/looking-for-software-to-facilitate-printing-of-online-content or http://superuser.com/questions/79773/how-to-turn-webpages-into-pdf :) Seriously though, unless asking for a particular solution using the data dump, I think this question is suited for Super User.

Comment: @S.Mark - doesn't work so well if the question has too many answers to fit on one page.

Comment: @Gnoupi: you do know that Super User is web-related and thus it will be killed!

Comment: @Ivo - hey, I barely managed to vote-close anything since the two new moderators are on their adrenaline rush, I'm adding chances :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StackPrinter](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/) Does just that

Answer (score 3):

If you want XML, then maybe the Atom feeds are good enough?

([Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/7931))

Answer (score 1):

This is something that could be done from the Data Dump, or, when it is released, the API.

Comment: Just wait 6 to 8 weeks

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use onenote, evernote or zoho?