# Is it possible to download the data dump only for some tags?

Tags: support, data-dump

I've seen that it's possible to download the SO public data dump [Where is Stack Overflow's public data dump?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-is-stack-overflows-public-data-dump) , is it possible to filter it before downloading?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible. But why? Are you worried about your bandwidth, or something else?

Comment: Something similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20823/stack-overflow-portable-edition , I'd like to use it offline

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't explain why you want it filtered before downloading - you can download it all and filter yourself. No?

Comment: I imagined that since now stack overflow provides the data explorer, I could perform the query on their server and download only the output. I haven't found how big is an unzipped dump, I don't know if I can process it